# Mat-expansion-panel-content height responsive

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using the component mat `<mat-expansion-panel>` from angular material abd I wabt to set the height in function of his parent. If I set the height to 10%, 1%... nothing occurs, but if I set it to 10px it works. But I need to set the height with percentage. I override the class `.mat-expansion-panel-content` to do this.

Why can't I do this with percentage but I can with px?

Comment: whenever you want to apply `height`, it has to carried from the top body to the desired element.. otherwise you wont be able to apply it in `%`, you could try `vh`

Comment: @PankajParkar yes, I know that with ```vh``` it works, but I i prefer to do it with ```%```